# Автоматизация нажимания кнопки "Сохранить как" во всплывающем окне IE11

Tags: java, автоматизация

Такая проблема, никак не могу найти подход к нажатию кнопки Сохранить или Сохранить как во всплывающем окне IE11. Пользуюсь Java+AutoItX, но то ли руки кривые, то ли голова дурная, ничего не получается. [image: Окно загрузки]

Передавать просто нажатие кнопок типа {ENTER} или {TAB} вообще не вариант. Может быть есть другие инструменты, которые способны работать с окнами DirectUIHWND или IEFrame. Получить Title окна могу, получить HAndle тоже просто, а вот как получить список кнопок или нажать конкретную кнопку не получается.

Comment: С автоитом утилита поставляется вроде - не помню как называется - позволяет анализировать окна и их элементы при перетаскивании "мишени" из окна утилиты на интересующий элемент целевого окна.
Я думаю, проанализировав всплывающий диалог загрузки этой "мишенью" - много вопросов разрешится.

Comment: Различные программы от AutoIt до Spy++ ничего не дают, содержимого IEFrame не показывает. Есть еще какие -нибудь предложения? Рассмотрю любые

Comment: Есть старый вариант со времён написания ботов для флеш игр - это скриншот участка окна (нижняя часть окошка, высоту можно посчитать по пикселям), поиск картинки соответствующей нужной кнопке (точнее, похожей на неё) и клик уже в той области окна, где "нащупали" кнопку. Но в данной области такое решение врядли целесообразно.

Comment: Есть такое средство под названием TestComplite так вот оно каким-то образом умеет общаться с такого рода объектами. Не знаю насколько это актуально